# php composer autoload on phpoffice/phpexcel fails

Tags: php, composer-php, phpexcel, autoload

I installed the package phpoffice/phpexcel via composer. Anyway the autoload does not work. I tried every combination of namespace to call the class but it's not there:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPExcel\\PHPExcel' not found in
```

The code that is calling it:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel\PHPExcel();
```

composer.json looks nice:

```
{
  "name": "Bjc/Iis",
  "description": "A complete software suite for commerce",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": ["commerce"],
  "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@me"
        }
    ],
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "5.*",
    "components/jquery": "2.*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.*",
    "zendframework/zend-barcode": "*",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {},
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Bjc\\Iis\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

The command "composer update" ran nicely. The files of phpoffice/phpexcel also are in vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel as expected.

I call the composer autoloader in my script as follows (and it works e.g. with phpmailer):

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Phpexcel also has references in all the autoloader files of composer:

vendor/composer/autoload_static has (beside others) these lines:

```
public static $prefixesPsr0 = array (
        'P' =>
        array (
            'PHPExcel' =>
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

And vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php looks like that:

```
// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
);
```

Anybody who can see my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`PHPExcel` class](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php) isn't in a namespace.

This works for me:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$phpExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$phpExcelObject = new PHPExcel();
```